# Limiting Stack Trace display depth with NLog Exception Renderer

Tags: .net, exception, logging, stack-trace, nlog

I am using NLog 4.4.5 to perform some exception logging in my Owin Web Api 2 project, and I would like to include a **partial** stack trace of my exceptions (i.e. the **top n frames of the stack**) in the logs.

My current layout is as follows:

```
layout="${longdate} | ${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}} | ${logger} | ${message} ${onexception:| ${exception:format=ShortType, Message, StackTrace}}"
```

I know already that NLog allows such a configuration in the [global `${stacktrace}` renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer), through the `topFrames` attribute:

> `${stacktrace:format=Enum:topFrames=Integer:skipFrames=Integer:separator=String`

However, when using the `StackFrame` format attribute of the *Exception layout renderer*, which is the recommended way of performing exception logging, the documentation does not specify an equivalent to `topFrames` for filtering the display of the stack trace.

Has anyone found a workaround to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed not possible without code. The `${stacktrace}` renderer, renders the stacktrace of the log call and not the exception.

But with some code this is possible. This example uses NLog 4.4:

1. Create a subclass for `ExceptionLayoutRenderer`
2. Override (it's virtual) the `AppendStackTrace` method.

e.g.

```cs
[LayoutRenderer("myException")]
[ThreadAgnostic]
public class MyExceptionLayoutRenderer : ExceptionLayoutRenderer 
{
    //new option, settable from config
    public int StackDepth {get;set;}

    protected override void AppendStackTrace(StringBuilder sb, Exception ex)
    {
        //sb.Append(...)
    }


}
```

3. Don't forget to register it, if there isn't a separate dll. As soon as possible: `LayoutRenderer.Register<MyExceptionLayoutRenderer>("myException")`

Usage `${myException:format=ShortType, Message, StackTrace:StackDepth=3}`